# Error: Module org.apache.cordova.console does not exist

Tags: ios, apache, cordova, plugins

So I am currently working on a contract to create a hybrid mobile app using phonegap. I am not sure exactly went wrong, and becuase of disclosure agreements my hands are somewhat tied on which code I can post.

Upon building the app, I get the splashscreen, then sometimes I get the loading pinwheel to infinity and other times I get the dreaded white screen. Any ideas on what could have caused this out of the blue. Hadn't touched the code over the weekend. Any specific areas of the code that you need to see that would help, don't hesitate to ask.

Xcode 5.1.1, ios 6 emulator

The **error** reads as follows:

```
Error: Module org.apache.cordova.console does not exist.

deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

Channel not fired: onPluginsReady

Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

Comment: please provide more info: ide, versions, sim or device

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and found out that some of my plugins were not 3.0 compatible.  My plugin javascript files were missing this like at the top of their file which was not adding the plugin id to the moduleMap used by the pluging manager.

cordova.define("com.plugin.softkeyboard.softkeyboard", function(require, exports, module) {

I had to go through each javascript file and add the above line with the correct id.

Maybe cordova build adds this line automatically for you?